# At maximum how many rows can be in the SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server

Normally we can give more values, at the maximum, how many rows a table can have in SQL Server? After that we can't add a new row.

Comment: More than you'll ever need......

Comment: so it doesn't have limit, is it so?

Comment: It will stop as soon as you've filled all your available disks - obviously.

Comment: Ok. Its upto the storage disk space, am i correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of edge cases (outside of the obvious disk space issue) where SQL Server will prevent you from adding more rows, not about number of rows exactly but thought worth mentioning:

- you have an `IDENTITY` column and you hit the end of the range for the data type, e.g. 255 for `TINYINT`, 2,147,483,647 for `INT`, some ungodly number that starts with a 9 - possibly the number of inches to the sun and back - for `BIGINT`, etc. When you try to insert the next row, you'll get error message 815 about overflowing the type. This has nothing to do with the number of rows already in the table, per se, but rather the number of rows you've already tried to insert (without re-seeding the `IDENTITY` column). If you have a high percentage of rollbacks (or a large number of successful inserts), you may want to keep track of the max value in this column over time.
- if you have a heap with a non-unique index, or a clustered index that is not unique, you won't be able to store more than 2 * 2,147,483,647 unique index key combinations. When you try to insert (2 * 2,147,483,647) + 1 rows with a value of `1` in an `INT` column that is the only column in a clustered index, you will get error message 666 about exhausting the *uniqueifier*. This is because the uniqueifier (which helps SQL Server identify a row when there is no true key) is only 4 bytes, which means it can't exceed the capacity of an `INT` (it does use both positive and negative, unlike `IDENTITY` unless configure it as such, which is why you get double). Now why you would ever do this, <shrug>... but you could.
- in the VLDB space, a database can only be 524,272 terabytes. Again a very edge case, but if you have a humongous data warehouse then obviously at some point the number of rows - depending on row size - will put you near this limit. I think petabyte databases, while they allegedly exist in some corner of some lab somewhere, are largely theoretical at this point. I suppose technically the *"Limited by available storage"* statement on the [Max Capacity page for SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) could take this max size into account, or they could just assume that nobody will ever have more than 524,272 terabytes of storage available to a single instance of SQL Server (which is probably a reasonable assumption today, but so was 640K of RAM, once :-)).

There are probably other similarly academic cases, but those are three that I thought of immediately when I saw the title of the question. They're very obscure and mostly academic, but I still thought they should be included in the discussion.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Microsoft specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx):

> Rows per table: Limited by available storage

Comment: Ok. Then how much available storage we can allocate for a particular database?

Comment: in Express Edition 2005,2008 it is 4Gb, 2008R2=10Gb, full editions=HD free space where database/log files are placed

Comment: Really Thanks. Can you tell me how to upgrade to full editions?

Comment: You should buy (or download trial version from Microsoft site) full version of SQL Server, then run file/ISO/CD installation. On Maintenance section you have "Edition upgrade" option.

Answer (score 2):

The number of rows in SQL Server is limited only by the storage available to the database itself. Unless you're hitting *that* limit, I doubt you'll ever run into a situation where you can't add rows to a table.

What is the problem, exactly? That would help. Error messages?

Comment: Actually one of my friend attend the interview, they asked him this question, i also dont know, that why.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a number of rows limit and not sure whether there is such a number. But I know tables with over 100 million rows.

If you are looking for a way to restrict your program to a maximum number of records, probably you should do that programmatically. AFAIK SQL Server doesn't expose such a property to you.

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT rows supports upto 2 billion, if we having more than 2 billion records, we have to move to ROWCOUNT_BIG, so i am thinking it can have more than 2 billion records, but i am want to know the maximum records.

Comment: Just FYI `@@ROWCOUNT` doesn't necessarily measure the number of rows in a table, it measures the number of rows affected by a SELECT or DML statement (so there is an intersection where the statement happens to be "SELECT * FROM table" - but if you're doing that on a table with 2 billion or more rows, have fun).